# What to write in onAdLeftApplication() and onAdClosed()?, because clicking on Admob ads wont let return to my App

Tags: android, callback, admob, onresume

I have an **Admob ad** on my main activity. When I click on the ad, it opens the default browser to show publicity. But I cannot go back to
 the main activity in my Android app, it will just show the Android default screen or the browser screen, even if I select my App with the square button menu of the device.

I guess I must write code on the callbacks of the Admob ads, which will let me reload my main screen.
 But what instructions do I exactly need? Any coding ideas? Thanks

```
 @Override
 public void onAdLeftApplication() { 
 // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
 ...?
 super.onAdLeftApplication();
 }

 @Override
 public void onAdClosed() {
 // Code to be executed when when the user is about to return
 // to the app after tapping on an ad.
 ...?
 super.onAdClosed();
 }
```